# Ugh, I decant even

Tags: mathematics, metapuzzles, decanting-problems

You know those [decanting-problems](/questions/tagged/decanting-problems), where you have two jugs of different sizes, and a water fountain, and you need to get a specific amount of water into one of the jugs using the smallest number of transfers? I came up with a decanting problem like that, but then it turned out that there were two solutions tied for "smallest number of transfers".

In those solutions, how full did the larger jug end up?

CLARIFICATION: In problems of this sort, it doesn't matter which jug ends up containing the target volume.

Comment: "I came up with a decanting problem like that," Please share.

Comment: @ABcDexter Well, that would be something of a spoiler, wouldn't it? The good news is, once someone posts the answer to *this* puzzle, you'll be able to as well.

Comment: Well, to answer your question, "how full did the larger jug end up" Exactly what was asked in the question. say 3L an 5L jug, and we need 4L, we would get 4L in the 5L jug in say n steps. A simple way is : to BFS the solution to check if it's possible and optimal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. I'm not asking anything about graph search algorithms. I'm just asking how full the larger jug was. You don't need any additional information.

Comment: In the case of 3 and 5 liter jugs and a 4 liter target, there's only one optimal solution.

Comment: Ok, I am voting to close this question as it is unclear what exactly you are trying to ask. If you are asking about the final volume of water Larger jug contains, then it has to be the amount of water asked in the question. This is only for cases when the volume asked is larger than the smaller jug as it's obvious it won't be able to fit that much.

Comment: We're getting into spoiler territory here, but note that I did *not* ask "what is the final volume of water the larger jug contains". Give it some more thought, try to come up with some examples, see if you can detect a pattern.

Comment: Does emptying a full jug count as a "pour"?

Comment: @DKrueger Yes. Any time water is transferred from one container/source to another container/sink, that's one pour. (I've reworded to "transfer" to make that less ambiguous.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two solutions to be equally fast

> a kind of symmetry is required. More precisely the empty part of the big jug must be symmetric to the filled part. In other words, the big jug will end up **half full**.

Explanation:

> The big jug (volume $V$) can start either with $0$ or $V$ filling, which is already symmetric around $\frac{V}{2}$. In the first step one can transfer the volume of the small jug $v$ in or out of the big one, so its filling after the first transfer is either $v$ or $V-v$, which again has the same distance to the final filling. 
>  In the next step one could either revert the previous one (which doesn't bring you closer to the required filling) or again withdraw or add a volume of $v$ to the big jug – unless the volume would exceed $[0, V]$. In the second case the big jug has now a filling of $V$ or $0$ and the small one of $2v - V$ or $V - v$, respectively. Again, one can see that the symmetry between around the fillings $\frac{V}{2}$ and $\frac{v}{2}$ are maintained. 
>  Also in all further steps **this symmetry can not be broken**, because for every transfer there is an opposite operation on the "mirror image", that instead of pouring $n$ liters from jug A to jug B pours it the other way round. 
>
>  Two symmetric paths leading to the same solution in the same number of transfers requires the two paths to meet. This is exactly the case in the symmetry axis, i.e. when the big jug is **half full**.

Example:

> [image]
>  One can clearly see the symmetry showing as the amount of air in the left path being equal to the amount of water in the right path.

Comment: That's a great way to explain it. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

My second thought is that:

> The larger jug will always be half full.

While I don't have a formal proof, I think that:

> If there are two optimal solutions, then the goal must be to get half the value of the larger jug. One solution will be to fill the small jug and move it to the large jug until it's half full, and the second will be to fill the large jug once and empty it into the smaller N times, until half of it had been emptied.

For example, consider when:

> The jugs are A at 4L and B at 1L and the target is 2L
> Two optimal solutions are:
> **Fill A, move A to B, dump B, move A to B**
> And,
> Fill B, move B to A, Fill B, move B to A**

If I have time I'll try to work on a more formal proof for why this would have to be the case.

Comment: You're very much on the right track, but the question asked "how full" the larger jug was. You don't need to involve the smaller jug or the target volume in the answer.

Comment: Can someone fix my spoilers? I'm stuck on mobile right now and can't get them to work...

Comment: Well done! Now about that proof....

Answer (score 1):

My guess is

> In one case it's empty, in another it's full

Because

> You have two jugs, a smaller one, denoted X and a larger one Y (Y > X) 
>  there are two solutions you can get to in two different 4-step ways: 
>  1) x:0 - 0:x   - x:x   - 2x-y:y 
>  2) 0:y - x:y-x - 0:y-x - y-x:0 
>  for both solutions to have the same amount in the small jug, we need y-x=2x-y, e.g. y=1.5x 
>  So I'm guessing the riddle is, take two jugs size 2,3 L and out 1L in the smaller one

I can't prove (yet?) that it's the only solution, but it's one anyway :)

Comment: In the case of 2 and 3 liter jugs, and a 1 liter target, there's only one optimal solution (of two steps): Fill the 3-liter jug from the fountain, then fill the 2-liter jug from the 3-liter jug.

Comment: @Sneftel you're right, but my answer works if you specify you want 1L in the smaller jar.. don't know if it's legal ?

Comment: It is legal, but the problem only requires "one of the jugs" to contain the target volume. In this case, the optimal solution has it in the larger one.

Comment: ...Though that was a little unclear in the way I worded the problem. I've added a clarification.